# How do I add a dynamic sitemap.xml to a CFWheels application?

Tags: coldfusion, sitemap, coldfusion-9, cfwheels

How do I configure CFWheels to display the following XML at http://mydomain.com/sitemap.xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

      <-- I'll add the <url> tags dynamically here later -->
</urlset>
```

I've removed the "sitemap.xml" from the `web.config` file.

After this I'm not sure what to do about creating the `controller` and `view`. Should I create a "sitemap.xml" folder in the "views" folder, then add an "index.cfm" file and then add the XML above?

Should I create a "sitemap.xml.cfc" file in the "controllers" folder? And what should the controller file contain?

Should it look something like this?

```
<cfcomponent extends="Controller" output="false">
<cfscript>  
  function init(){
    // Let CFWheels know what type of output this controller can 'provide'
    provides("xml");
  }

  function index(){

  }
</cfscript>
</cfcomponent>
```

Do I need to add an entry to the routes.cfm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Setting up the Controller

Your controller's `index()` method should look something like this. It's stored at `controllers/Sitemap.cfc`.

```
function init() {
    // Grab data about URLs from model or build an array of structs to pass to the view
    urls = model("page").findAll(); // This line is just an example

    // Call `renderWith()` to instruct Wheels that this requires a special content-type
    renderWith(urls);
}
```

### Setting up the View

Your view at `views/sitemap/index.xml.cfm` can then generate the required XML:

```
<cfoutput>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
        http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

    #includePartial(partial="url.xml", query=urls)#
</urlset>

</cfoutput>
```

Then you can implement a partial at `views/sitemap/_url.xml.cfm` representing a single item in your query or array. Let me know if you're using something other than a query, and I can modify my example above.

```
<cfoutput>

<url>
    <loc>#arguments.uri#</loc>
    <loc>#arguments.updatedAt#</loc>
</url>

</cfoutput>
```

Keep in mind that when you use a partial like this, query columns or struct keys get placed into the `arguments` scope, which is why I'm referencing `arguments.uri` and `arguments.updatedAt` in my fictitious example.

### Accessing via URL

Depending on your server's URL rewriting capabilities, you may need to try a couple things to get the URL to do what you want.

You may be able to do something like this in `config/routes.cfm` (but I've only tested this on Apache):

```
<cfset addRoute(pattern="sitemap.[format]", controller="sitemap", action="index")>
<cfset addRoute(pattern="sitemap", controller="sitemap", action="index")>
```

Then you can load the URL at `http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml`

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
<cfset addRoute(pattern="sitemap.xml", controller="sitemap", action="index")>
<cfset addRoute(pattern="sitemap", controller="sitemap", action="index")>
```

Again, you can load the URL at `http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml`

Finally, if that doesn't work, remove the extra lines from `config/routes.cfm` and load this URL (which most definitely will always work regardless):

```
`http://www.example.com/sitemap?format=xml`.
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth examples. Unfortunately, the routes aren't working for `http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml` either. `http://www.example.com/sitemap/` works but `http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml` ends up triggering the onmissingtemplate.cfm and displays a "File Not Found!" message.

Comment: You may want to compare `web.config` and `.htaccess` in the GitHub repo and see if you can finesse `web.config` to work better with dots in the path.

https://github.com/cfwheels/cfwheels/blob/new-master/web.config
https://github.com/cfwheels/cfwheels/blob/new-master/.htaccess

Comment: Can you see if this patch works? Looks like something got broken in the CFML in Wheels 1.1.7. https://github.com/cfwheels/cfwheels/commit/aa04eb927daa429a3bdc3a4d4e1d221c823e63b3

Comment: I see you accepted my answer. Did the patch in my above comment work?

Comment: Yes, Thanks! Using `sitemap.[format]` with the [patch](https://github.com/cfwheels/cfwheels/commit/aa04eb927daa429a3bdc3a4d4e1d221c823e63b3) does work. I should mention that there is another option for those who don't wish to apply this patch which is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9112039/675590).

Answer (score 1):

First, you will have to have configured your webserver to do full URL Rewriting, if you haven't already.  That way you won't have to have index.cfm in your URL (http://mydomain.com/index.cfm/foo/bar becomes http://mydomain.com/foo/bar).

Once that is in place, modify your config/routes.cfm like so:

```
<cfset addRoute(name="sitemap",
        pattern="/sitemap.xml",
        controller="sitemap",
        action="list") />
```

Then you can add your XML code here:

/views/sitemap/list.cfm

and, optionally a controller here:

/controllers/Sitemap.cfc (with a function named list)

*edit*

Since the above isn't working quite right, I took a look at the stock rewrite rules that come with CFWheels, and noticed a big problem:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(flex2gateway|jrunscripts|cfide|cfformgateway|cffileservlet|railo-context|files|images|javascripts|miscellaneous|stylesheets|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|rewrite.cfm|favicon.ico)($|/.*$) [NC]
```

Note the "sitemap.xml".  Remove this from your list, leaving you with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(flex2gateway|jrunscripts|cfide|cfformgateway|cffileservlet|railo-context|files|images|javascripts|miscellaneous|stylesheets|robots.txt|rewrite.cfm|favicon.ico)($|/.*$) [NC]
```

You may have to restart/reload your web server.  But that should do it.

*edit*

One last idea - you could add a rewrite rule in your webserver that redirects requests for /sitemap.xml to /sitemap, since you know that one works.

Comment: This isn't working when addressing http://domain.com/sitemap.xml. It does work for http://domain.com/sitemap/. To remove the layout, I added  `renderWith(data="#urls#", layout="false");` to the `list()` function of in the controller.

Comment: Removing "sitemap.xml" from the rewrite pattern was the first thing I did. In my case I removed it from the web.config file as I'm using the IIS rewrite module. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks for you help Jake. Your suggestion to modify the rewrite does work with some modifications which you can get a gist for [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9112039/675590)