# How do I render pages with "file" extensions like xml, json, csv, etc. in CFWheels with the file type in the URL?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfwheels

I can't seem to figure out how to create pages in `CFWheels` with clean URLs that contain "file" extensions.

I'd like to be able to do the following:

- http://www.example.com/products.xml
- http://www.example.com/products.json

As apposed to this:

- http://www.example.com/products?format=xml
- http://www.example.com/products?format=json

I've read through these [docs](http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-1/chapter/responding-with-multiple-formats) but am still unclear about the actual implementation.

Lets say I have a controller (`/controllers/Product.cfc`) that looks something like the following:

```
<cfcomponent extends="Controller">

    <cffunction name="init">
        <cfset provides("html,json,xml")>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="index">
        <cfset products = model("product").findAll(order="title")>
        <cfset renderWith(products)>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

How do I implement the view? Should it be `views/products/index.xml.cfm`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product><!-- product data goes here --></product>
</products>
```

How do I implement the `routes.cfm`?

I should note that I'm also using the default [web.config](https://github.com/cfwheels/cfwheels/blob/new-master/web.config) and have `<cfset set(URLRewriting="On")>` in the `config/setting.cfm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumption about routes is correct. But you have to make sure rewriting works properly, say not partially. You can access urls like `/controller/action`, right? Not `/rewrite.cfm/controller/action`.

So route definition can look like this:

```
<cfset addRoute(name="indexProducts", pattern="products.[format]", controller="product", action="index") />
```

In the `index` method you'll have `params.format` populated with actual value, wich you want to validate (`ListFind` should work).

View template for this page should have the name of its action: `/views/product/index.cfm`. Nothing special needed here unless you want to load views conditionally, for example separate view for each format. In this case you want to check out [renderPage](http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-1/function/renderPage) function. It can be used to override the default view.

**UPDATE**

OK, I've tested this solution and it wont work. Routes do not support anything except slashes as delimiter. So this kind of route can work only this way:

```
<cfset addRoute(name="indexProducts", pattern="products/[format]", controller="product", action="index") />
```

I guess we don't want to modify CFWheels code (which is bad idea without further pull request any way), so I would recommend using web-server rewriting. For example, in Apache it may look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^products\.(xml|json|html)$ product/index?format=$1 [NS,L]
```

You are using IIS, so it should look similar to this (NOT TESTED):

```
<rule name="Products listing" enabled="true">
    <match url="^products\.(xml|json|html)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="product/index?format={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Think it's better approach than trying to create controllers named like `ProductsXml`, `ProductsJson` etc.

Comment: The rewriting is working correctly but adding a file extension like ".xml" isn't working. Maybe I should try it on a new clean CFWheels site.

Comment: It turns out that CFWheels [1.1.7 broke the formats functionality by no longer allowing periods](https://github.com/cfwheels/cfwheels/commit/aa04eb927daa429a3bdc3a4d4e1d221c823e63b3)! So I believe your initial answer would have worked for some versions of CFWheels. Also, your suggestion for rewriting should work quite nicely. Thanks again!